# Synchronize two angular ui bootstrap carousels

Tags: javascript, angularjs, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am trying to create two synchronized carousels in a page using angular ui bootstrap. I tried setting variable

```
 myinterval
```

Same. For two carousel same. But after sometime they go out of sync. Also if user hovers over one carousel it should also pause the other. Any pointers on how to achieve this.

Here is a plunker example http://plnkr.co/edit/SOy6yn7MAQ98tgmvVucC?p=preview

Comment: I don't think this version of carousel supports this functionality. It receives the value in milliseconds of interval, but it is not the same invoking interval function.

Comment: I have updated the plunkr to use latest version

Comment: Was able to solve it with help of these threads

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24686119/how-do-you-bind-to-angular-uis-carousel-slide-events

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24952433/setting-active-slide-on-angular-ui-bootstrap-carousel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was able to solve it with help of these threads.

[How do you Bind to Angular-UI's Carousel Slide Events?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24686119/how-do-you-bind-to-angular-uis-carousel-slide-events)

[Setting active slide on angular-ui-bootstrap carousel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24952433/setting-active-slide-on-angular-ui-bootstrap-carousel)

1) Get the current slide of first carousel by

```
$scope.$watch(function () {
  for (var i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
  if (slides[i].active) {
      return slides[i];
     }
    }
  }, function (currentSlide, previousSlide) {
      if (currentSlide !== previousSlide) {
       console.log('currentSlide:', currentSlide);
    }
 });
```

2) Now that you have the current slide. Set the second carousel with this index.